# Beautiful Soup if Class "Contains" or Regex?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If my class names are constantly different say for example:

```
listing-col-line-3-11 dpt 41
listing-col-block-1-22 dpt 41
listing-col-line-4-13 CWK 12
```

Normally I could do:

```
for EachPart in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "ClassNamesHere"}):
            print EachPart.get_text()
```

There are way too many class names to work with here so a bunch of these are out.

I know Python doesn't have a ".contains" I would normally use but it does have an "in". Though I haven't been able to work out a way to incorporate that.

I'm hoping there's a way to do this with regex. Though again my Python syntax is really letting me down I've been trying variations on:

```
regex = re.compile('.*listing-col-.*')
    for EachPart in soup.find_all(regex):
```

But that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

BeautifulSoup supports [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which allow you to select elements based on the content of particular attributes. This includes the selector `*=` for contains.

The following will return all `div` elements with a `class` attribute containing the text 'listing-col-':

```
for EachPart in soup.select('div[class*="listing-col-"]'):
    print EachPart.get_text()
```

Answer (score 33):

You can try this for loop:

```
regex = re.compile('.*listing-col-.*')
for EachPart in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : regex}):
        print EachPart.get_text()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid regex by using partial matching with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho)...

Input:

```py
html = """\
<div class="listing-col-line-3-11 dpt 41">A</div>
<div class="listing-col-block-1-22 dpt 41">B</div>
<div class="listing-col-line-4-13 CWK 12">C</div>
"""
```

Partial matching code:

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

soup = Soup(html)
divs = soup.find("div", {"class": "listing-col-"}, partial=True)
[div.text for div in divs]
```

Output:

```py
['A', 'B', 'C']
```