# BeautifulSoup find class contains some specific words

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have searched around to find about how to find a class with name contains some word but I don't find it. I want to take the information from class named with word footer on it.

`<div class="footerinfo">
      <span class="footerinfo__header">
      </span>
</div>`

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="w-container container-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this but it still don't work

```
soup.find_all('div',class_='^footer^'):
```

and

```
 soup.find_all('div',class_='footer*'):
```

Does anyone have any idea on doing this?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660417/beautiful-soup-if-class-contains-or-regex

Comment: you provided a wrong footer indicator,  '^footer^, this is not the same as "footer" so it doesnt find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors which allow you to select elements based on the content of particular attributes. This includes the selector *= for contains.

```
for ele in soup.select('div[class*="footer"]'):
    print (ele)
```

or regex

```
import re

regex = re.compile('.*footer.*')
soup.find_all("div", {"class" : regex})
```