# Using BeautifulSoup to extract part of class name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Because the class names are changing for each item, I'd like to extract the information based on part of the class name (carrier-text in the example). However, it does not work...

```py
html = """
<div class="dErF-carrier-text">
Alaska Airlines 398 </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('div',class_="carrier-text").text
print(text)
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660417/beautiful-soup-if-class-contains-or-regex

Answer (score 0):

#### How to fix?

You can solve your issue by using `css selectors` that looks if `class` contains your substring:

```
soup.select_one('div[class*="carrier-text"]')
```

###### Please note

*It will work for your specific example, but take care if there are elements with `class` that also contains your substring, then you may have to select more specific.*

##### Options

Cause your question is not that clear - Extracting the `text` or the `class`?

###### Get the text

```
soup.select_one('div[class*="carrier-text"]').get_text(strip=True)
```

###### Get the class

```
soup.select_one('div[class*="carrier-text"]')['class']
```

#### Example

```
html = """
<div class="dErF-carrier-text">
Alaska Airlines 398 </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.select_one('div[class*="carrier-text"]').get_text(strip=True)
```

#### Output

```
Alaska Airlines 398
```