# Beautiful soup if class not like "string" or regex

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I know that beautiful soup has a function to match classes based on regex that contains certain strings, based on a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660417/beautiful-soup-if-class-contains-or-regex). Below is a code example from that post:

```
regex = re.compile('.*listing-col-.*')
for EachPart in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : regex}):
        print EachPart.get_text()
```

Now, is it possible to do the opposite? Basically, find classes that do not contain a certain regex. In SQL language, it's like:

```
where class not like '%test%'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This actually can be done by using ***Negative Lookahead***

**Negative Lookahead** has the following syntax `(?!«pattern»)` and matches if `pattern` does not match what comes before the current location in the input string.

In your case, you could use the following regex to match **all classes** that **don’t** contain `listing-col-` in their name:

```py
regex = re.compile('^((?!listing-col-).)*$')
```

Here’s the pretty simple and straightforward explanation of this regex `^((?!listing-col-).)*$`:

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- **Capturing Group** `((?!listing-col-).)*`

  - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
  - **Negative Lookahead** `(?!listing-col-)`.
    Assert that the Regex below does not match.
    `listing-col-` matches the characters `listing-col-` literally (case sensitive)
  - `.` matches any character
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

##### Also, you may find the https://regex101.com site useful

It will help you test your patterns and show you a detailed explanation of each step. It's your best friend in writing regular expressions.

Comment: thank you so much! This works perfectly and I can even create a list of tags to exclude using your approach as well!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is utilizing regex directly.
You can refer to [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word).

Or you can introduce a function to implement the logic and pass it to `find_all` as a parameter.
You can refer to https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector syntax with :not() pseudo class and * contains operator

```
data = [i.text() for i in soup.select('div[class]:not([class*="listing-col-"])')]
```